# Mulitplying ints in list by their indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to multiply ints in list so that the first int is multiplied by the last one and so on. I came up with  that

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l1 = l[::-1]
l2 = [x*y for x,y in zip(l,l1)]
```

but that doesn't work as I want it to because there is always an int that will match int in the other list. I want to have it in one list so there will be a certain int ( middle one) that wont find another int to be multiplied with and for that case I need it to be replaced with square root of this int. The outcome of this would be ( for l above)

```
[5,8,square root of 3].
```

So basically it would need to go by indexes I think , but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: "and so on" what do you mean by this?

Comment: What's the expected output for the given `l`?

Comment: Now result `[5, 8, 9, 8, 5]` but what do you want?

Comment: The list will always be in odd length ?

Comment: To treat certain cases specially, you need to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Sam ,it appears so

Comment: @PiotrekWcisło I think I don't really understand what you want. You mention "indexes" several times, but you never use them. Instead you are just reversing one list. This will **always** result in the middle element being the same in both lists. If you really want indexes, you should look at the `enumerate()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply corresponding elements of list, take square root of middle element. Then cast your result to set to remove duplicates. However this won't preserve the order of elements

```
import math
list(set([math.sqrt(x) if x==y else x*y for x,y in zip(l,l[::-1])]))
```

Outputs:

```
[8, 1.7320508075688772, 5]
```

If you wish to preserve order of elements and remove duplicates you can use:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import math
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([math.sqrt(x) if x==y else x*y for x,y in zip(l,l[::-1])]))
```

Outputs:

```
[5, 8, 1.7320508075688772]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have it in one list so there will be a certain int ( middle one) that wont find another int to be multiplied with and for that case I need it to be replaced with square root of this int.

Since you have a special condition, you need an `if` statement. It will probably be easier to write with a for loop instead of a list comprehension:

```
l2 = []
for x, y in zip(l, l1):
    if x == y:
        l2.append(sqrt(x))
    else:
        l2.append(x * y)
```

Comment: well it almost works , maybe its because of my bad english but the problem here is that we get the same numbers twice whereas by going by indexes you get in once and thats what I want to achievie

Comment: @PiotrekWcisło Note that indices start at 0, not 1. Also, you should look at the `enumerate()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for now and then you can modify it according to your need:

```
import math
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
middle = int(len(l)/2)
final = []
total = len(l)

for value in range(total):
    if value < middle:
        final.append(l[value]*l[total-value-1]) 
    elif total%2 !=0:
        final.append(math.sqrt(l[value]))
        break
    else:
        break
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[5, 8, 1.7320508075688772]
```

Comment: `[l[i]*l[len(l)-1-i] if i != len(l)-1-i else math.sqrt(l[i]) for i in range((len(l)+1)//2)]`

Comment: Implementation is cumbersome and inefficient. Use smth like `odd_number_of_elements = total % 2` and `for index in range(total // 2)`.

Comment: @CristiFati loop is stopped by break at the middle of array - it the same as `index in range(total // 2)`

Comment: @splash58: I know, that part is (now) inefficient from lines of code perspective. There are however other things the `if` or `total%2 !=0` which can be dropped.

Comment: It's not clear for me that `total%2 !=0` `*can be dropped*. I check that point in code in my comment  above  by `if i != len(l)-1-i` that is not better :)

Comment: That part is to check whether the list is even or odd. If it is even, it will not do that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from math import sqrt

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = []
l_size=len(l)
mid_index=l_size/2

# lets multiply
for i in range(0, mid_index):
    l2.append(l[i]*l[-(i+1)])
# if the length is odd, middle element needs to be taken care of
if l_size%2:
     l2.append(sqrt(l[mid_index]))
print l2
```

Answer (score 0):

That produces your desired result:

```
from math import sqrt

end = len(l)//2
res = [x * y for x, y in zip(l[:end], reversed(l))] + [sqrt(l[end])]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[5, 8, 1.7320508075688772]
```